# instantiate a MenuItem

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have the following problem with a blackberry demo class:

```
MenuItem locatorItem = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Location Search"), 0x230020, 0);
            locatorItem.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler() 
            (...)
```

I am using Eclipse and a BlackBerry simulator to get this demo running and I get the 'Cannot instantiate the type MenuItem' error.  I don't know why and there's no suggestion to solve it.
I imported 'net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem;'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong type of MenuItem. `net.rim.device.api.ui.MenuItem` you are using is specific to the Blackberry.

If this is a J2ME Application/Midlet, just create a [`javax.microedition.lcdui.Command`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/lcdui/Command.html). They are turned into menu items on the blackberry.

If you're also using`net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen` or any other `net.rim` classes in the application, this is the way menu items are usually created:

```
function doSomething() {
   // Your Code Here
}

// In the function building your screen
MenuItem somethingMi = new MenuItem() {
  private MenuItem() { super("Do Something",100001, 5); }

  public void run() { doSomething() };
}

addMenuItem(somethingMI);
```